# How can I force an element in a LinearLayout to show his content - even if an element before has a fill_parent parameter?

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I'm always struggling with these kind of layout things:

[AnyCustomViewWhichShouldTakeAllLeftSpace|View|]

[View1|AnyCustoViewWhichShouldTakeAllLeftSpace|View2]

In case AnyCustoViewWhichShouldTakeAllLeftSpace has the parameter match_parent or fill_parent, View or View2 is not visible, because there is no space left.

Someone suggested to give the CustomView the weight of 1, just to let this view rendering at last. But this is not working in every case.

Is there anything in Android like in XAML/C#/WPF ? For example width=* (takeAllWhatYouGet, but NOT more)

Any good tutorials of good layout structures which deal with this explicite kind of problem?

Comment: do you want to give space to View1 and View2 first and then give whatever space is left to AnyCustoViewWhichShouldTakeAllLeftSpace?

Comment: yes! that describes it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you elaborate on under which circumstances does the CustomView with weight of 1 not work for you?
Assuming View 1 & View 2 are fixed height, the following works.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:background="#ff0000"
         />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/customview
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:background="#0000ff"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey... Thanks. I might had made a mistake in my implementation. I can't reproduce the layout where "weight" was not the solution. So I accept your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following the code

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:background="#0000ff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The middle view will occupy whatever space is left after rendering `view1` and `view2`